# Silverstripe migration, index and other pages not found. Why?

Tags: nginx, php, silverstripe

I recently migrated a silverstripe website from a server with apache2 to a new server with nginx. I followed these instructions: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/installation/nginx . I am using php5-fpm with tcp port (127.0.0.1:9000).
The problem is that i am facing "file not found." as soon as i try to reach the website from the browser.
I would appreciate any help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Which SilverStripe version?
2. Is there anything in the logs (both nginx and PHP)?

My slightly tuned nginx configuration for SilverStripe 3 looks like this: https://gist.github.com/xeraa/eab6bc9914e4b75009b8 — this might get you started

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
The log of nginx is reporting the following: fastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream. I am not sure about the version of silverstripe, i will have to check that from the old server. 
With you conf file i cannot restart nginx even thought i make the necessary changes.

Comment: Looks like ``SCRIPT_FILENAME`` in the nginx ``fastcgi_param`` directive is wrong. 1) have you set the correct ``root``? 2) With SilverStripe 3 it should be ``fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/framework/main.php;`` IMHO

Comment: Hi xeraa and thank you for your help. I managed to resolve the issue. I changed the nginx file according to this: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/2.3/installation/nginx and i had to install php-mysqlnd.